# Force to download image from external server

Tags: php, html

1. I want to implement a button that downloads an image uploaded in a external server.
2. HTML 5 download attribute does work, but in FireFox and IE10 it opens the image in a new window and the user still have to use the right click to save image as.

   ```
   <a href="https://externalserver/images/image.png" download="edited_image.png">Save</a>
   ```

I can force the download using PHP if the image is located in my server.

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];


download_file($file);

function download_file( $fullPath ){

    // Must be fresh start
    if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

// Required for some browsers
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

  // File Exists?
   if( file_exists($fullPath) ){


    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) {

      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
      default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } else
    die('File Not Found');

}
?>
```

HTML

```
<a href="/php/download.php?file=image01.jpg">Download1</a>
```

1. Is there a way to avoid with the HTML5 download attribute the problem to open the image in a new window in FF and IE? -Chrome works great-.
2. Is there a way to do it with PHP but when the image is located at and external server?

It will be great to do it any way, HTML 5 or PHP. Thanks for any help. Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy it to your server and download from there.

```
file_put_contents($fullpath, 
    file_get_contents('https://externalserver/images/image.png'));        
header("Pragma: public"); // wtf?
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");  
// omg what have you been reading?
header("Cache-Control: private",false);  
// obviously not rfc 2616
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($generatedPath)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile( $fullPath );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
1.From where you get the var $generatedPath?
2. In the file_get_contents I need to get the URL send by the link in the html part of the code which is $file so it will be like this:

    file_put_contents($fullpath,file_get_contents($fullPath)); am I right?

Comment: Fullpath is whatever you want it to be. If you're not planning on caching the file then use tmpnam() if you do plan on caching it then (for example) the sha1 of the URL. 2 - yes

Answer (score 0):

For the php part. If you have the URL of the image you can use many approach.

An easy one would be a simple call to file_get_content to retrieve the image binary data in a variable .

After you can save it to the disk or do whatever you want with it.